# How to filter points that are lying on the shortest path?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a task: a truck departs from a warehouse located at point (0, 0).
A function is given a `List<Point> points` that are waiting for the truck and `N` value represents a number of points in which the truck has to arrive such as `N <= points.size()`. The truck doesn't have to go round all the points, only `N` of them.
Return `List<Point>` size of `N` that truck has to visit doing the shortest path.

```
public List<Point> route(final List<Point> points, final int N);

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getters
public final class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
}
```

Looking at this picture, if `N = 2`
[image]
POINT_2 and POINT_3 have to be chosen because in this case, the truck covers 2 units. It isn't necessary that chosen points are equal to points closest to the start point.

If POINT_1 and POINT_2 are chosen then the truck rides 1 unit to POINT_1 and after 2 units to POINT_2 that in sum is 3 units.

Comment: Which is your implementation of route method?

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? This is just a problem description. Are you looking for the entire solution?

Comment: Just calculate the distance of all points from current point. Take the point to which you have shortest distance. Then make that point the start point and repeat until n times. Exclude the previous start point from the list on each iter.